# Compute the number of ways to arrange $n$ books on two bookshelves using generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, generating-functions

[image]

I have this exponential generating function for arranging $n$ books into **1** shelf:
$$\hat{a}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\frac{x^n}{n!} , \text{ with } a_n = n! \text{ for } n \geq 1 $$

My transformation to get the algebraic expression of $\hat{a}(x)$ is:
$$\hat{a}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right) - 1 = \frac{1}{1-x} - 1=\frac{x}{1-x}$$

Now I think the generating function for $(t_n)_{n \geq 2}$ is $\ \hat{t}(x) = \hat{a}^2(x)$, but I have a few questions:

1. The indices in this case are a bit odd: normally I would have multiplication of generating functions written as $\hat{t}(x)_{n \geq 0} = \hat{a}(x)_{n \geq 0} \times \hat{b}(x)_{n \geq 0}$, but in this case it is $\hat{t}(x)_{n \geq 2} = \hat{a}(x)_{n \geq 1} \times \hat{a}(x)_{n \geq 1}$. Is it an issue?
2. Also a way to amend the situation is to set $t_0 = t_1 = 0$, and $a_0 = 0$, which seems to agree with the way the problem is worded. Then we can have $\hat{t}(x)_{n \geq 2} = \hat{t}(x)_{n \geq 0}$, and $\hat{a}(x)_{n \geq 1} = \hat{a}(x)_{n \geq 0}$. Does this work?
3. The standard method after getting  $\hat{t}(x) = \frac{x^2}{(1-x)^2}$ (if we proceed with the multiplication above), is to find the partial fractions decomposition $\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{A}{1-x} + \frac{B}{1-x}$. But this doesn't seem possible. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you have $$\hat{a}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}\,?$$

Comment: My bad. The expression without $n!$ is after $a_n = n!$ was put in.

Comment: For your questions: (1) I don't know why you think there is any issue; (2) I have no clue what you mean by the indices $n\geq 2$ and $n\geq 0$ (they make no sense); (3) the partial fraction decomposition does not work here (you need negative binomial expansion).  At the end, you should get $$\hat{t}(x)=x^2+2x^3+3x^4+\ldots=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\,(n-1)\,n!\,\frac{x^n}{n!}\,,$$ which is the correct generating function for $t_n$.  This can be readily verified, using a combinatorial argument.

Comment: For 3, instead of partial fractions, if you know the series for $1/(1-x)$, then the series for $x^2/(1-x)^2$ can be derived by first taking the derivative of the above series, and then multiplying all terms by $x^2$.

Comment: Don't see why you need indices $n\geq 2$, $n\geq1$, and $n\geq 0$ because $a_0=0$, $t_0=0$, and $t_1=0$, so $\hat{a}(x)$ will not have a constant term anyhow.  Likewise, $\hat{t}(x)$ starts with the quadratic term.  Your strange indices are making things confusing.

Comment: Thank you all. Both methods gave me the right answer. It seems that I over-complicated the problem in (1) and (2) a bit.